# Laravel 8.x - URI in custom success response

Tags: php, html, laravel, response

In an application I'm building, I return the user to a program list page, after they have edited an academic `Program`.

I'm using the `return redirect()->with()` methods to return to the list page, however I am trying to append an in-page link to the success message, so the user can jump to the edited program's thumbnail, after clicking on that message.

I have tried multiple combinations but this is as far as I've gotten:

```
return redirect('/education/programs')->with('success', "The changes to the ".  `<a href="#program-.$program->id.">`.'program'.`</a>`. " have been saved.");
```

This unfortunatelly results to a plain text "The changes to the program have been saved." message, with no clickable uri whatsoever.

The reason why I do not append the uri to the redirect() method, is because I want the message to display on the top of the page, and give the user the option to jump to it only if they choose to.

Any idea how I could make it work in this form ? Or perhaps some other suggestions ? Thank you in advance!

Comment: You can render HTML in your view as, `{!! $success!!}`

Comment: You're using ```Backquote ` ```

Comment: @sta Unfortunatelly this just breaks my whole html page

Comment: change it to this `'The changes to the <a href="#program-' . $program->id .'"> program</a> have been saved.'`

Comment: @bhucho thank you, this in combination with sta's {!!$message!!} made it work!

Comment: Hey, I know I'm coming back to this but it's an extension of the original post really. In the href again, how can I put a link on another page of my application using the url() method ? This simply does not work so far:         return redirect()->back()->with('success', 'The <a href="url(`/education/programs#program-' . $course->program->id .'`)">course</a> was created successfully.'); (Note: I've used the ` signs but Stackoverflow parses it as code section)